# Simplexml & php rss feed (view image from rss feed)

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplexml

I am trying to parse the yahoo pipe rss feed. this is the feed

```
<channel>
.......

<item>
......
<media:content url="http://cdn.c.photoshelter.com/img-get/I0000IhrAERY1qOs/s/900/900/Indonesia-Java-Bandung-3106-Bandung.jpg" />
<media:thumbnail url="http://cdn.c.photoshelter.com/img-get/I0000IhrAERY1qOs/s/900/900/Indonesia-Java-Bandung-3106-Bandung.jpg" />
</item>
</channel>
```

How do I get the image (`<media:thumbnail`) from that RSS feed? I've done to try this, but there is no result. this is my code

```
<? $feed = file_get_contents('http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=ce435780a2b72feb40c0b7446b92e660&_render=rss');
$rss = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
$ns_dc = $item->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
echo $ns_dc->thumbnail ; echo '<br>';
}
?>
```

the problem is "SimpleXmlElement" do not generate category name and media thumbnail image.
help me please
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `echo $ns_dc->thumbnail;` prints out the text contents of the `<media:thumbnail>` element, even though it has none.  To access the value in the `url` attribute, use the following:

```
echo $ns_dc->thumbnail->attributes()->url;
```